# android new versio app can't rollout to production

Tags: android, google-play

i have uploaded my app to playstore and couldnt download it from there because i faced this issue "your device isnt compatible with this version". on further analysis I could found out that I have used feature "android.hardware.type.watch" in my manifest

now after i remove this line from the manifest and uploaded a new version to production im getting an error
"You can't rollout this release because it doesn't allow any existing users to upgrade to the newly added APKs."

i encreased the versioncode number but the message remains
how can i fix it and upload a new version

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.appiness"
    >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:fullBackupContent="false"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_appiness_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="AppinessApplication"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_appiness_icon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:versionCode="10"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppinessProject"
        >
```

Comment: share manifest file

Comment: @Bhriguraj Salponia added in the post above

Comment: define versionCode in module build.gradle only, remove 'android:versionCode="10"' from manifest- https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning#appversioning

Comment: i tried it before i added this versionCode to the manifest but it didn't helped